# If I'm planning on buying a game but there might be some GSE giveaway for it, should I hold off?

Tags: support, promotional-grant

*Diablo III*...blah, blah, pre-order...going to buy regardless, but if it might incur a promotional grant gaming giveaway should I hold off?  Would the "receipt" need to be dated between some specified dates?

This is more a question about the behind-the-scenes business stuff, so while yes, this shouldn't matter in an ideal world, there's stuff that can complicate things.

Comment: Is there a reason (like an in-game bonus or something) for pre-purchasing it (now)?

Comment: I'd be interested to know about the receipt date thing. But I wouldn't rely on grants for all your games.

Comment: @Resorath I'm not *relying* on it (hence "buying regardless"), but there's no reason to unnecessary preclude obtaining one if it happens.

Comment: @JuanManuel for D3?  Not that I know of, but I was trying to be general.  Also figured if I could I'd just try to tick off one more thing on the never-ending to-do list of life.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a comment before that said if you bought it and *then* qualified for the grant, you could get reimbursed, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @MatthewRead I've heard that too, but can't find the root of it from an authoritative person.  If you can...

Comment: If you do buy it, and there's a grant, you can give proof of purchase for a reimburstment.  If there's not grant, well you bought it anyway so whats teh big deal :P

Comment: Every grant so far has offered reimbursement, and I don't know why that would change because it's less effort for the SE folks.  Just buy it and if you get lucky, hey, you get lucky.

Comment: For both of the last two grants, I had pre-purchased both games before the grants were even announced, and I was reimbursed by providing a receipt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it.  The comments on [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3876/6066):

> GraceNote was saying last week to go ahead and order one, and they could reimburse you if you were selected. – Ullallulloo Feb 1 at 21:07
>
> There is an electronic receipt you should get when making a purchase with Steam, Amazon, or any other online retailer. That will suffice for getting a refund, should you be selected. – Grace Note♦ Feb 1 at 21:26